# How to get specific data from collection? (Debugger)

Tags: java

I am beginner with debbuger. Can someone tell me how can i get this data:
[image]

I am trying to achieve variable String which will have role name.
Here is my code:

```
SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
Authentication authentication = context.getAuthentication();
```

Can someone help? :<

Comment: Did you **read the documentation**, i.e. the javadoc of [`Authentication`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.13.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/Authentication.html)? The field in the debugger is named `authorities`, so method `getAuthorities()` seems natural. It returns a `Collection`, so iterate it. Call `toString()` to get the `"ADMIN"` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `authentication.getAuthorities()` . Usually the way in which you can get the information you want is to simply add a `get` in front of the attribute name and cast the first letter to upper case.